# Spring MVC-showing object values in jsp

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring MVC,MYSQL, JdbcTemplate in my project.

When I am fetching data from db using drop down list box in JSP page

Instead of showing number upto 0-9. It is showing encrypted values.

The data type that I've passed here is int.

My Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
      public String executeSecurity(ModelMap model, Principal principal,@ModelAttribute SearchFiller searchFiller) {
      List<SearchFiller> adultsList=searchFlightDao.adultsList();
      model.addObject("adultsList", adultsList);
      String name = principal.getName();  
      model.addAttribute("author", name);
      return "welcome";   
     }
```

My part of JSP page:

```
<form:form action="index" method="get" modelAttribute="searchFiller">
```

.
.
.

```
           <tr>
                <td>Adults</td>
                <td><form:select path="adults">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                    <form:options items="${adultsList}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="adults" cssClass="error" /></td>
           </tr>
```

SearchFiller.java

```
private int adults;
getters and setters
```

Is this whether hashcode or encrypted form??
Right answer gets appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code snippats here of JSP and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer:

```
       <tr>
            <td>Adults</td>
            <td><form:select path="adults">
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                <form:options items="${adultsList}" itemValue="<propertyName_of_SearchFiller_pojo_you_want_to_pass_set_as_value_of_option>" itemLabel="<propertyName_of_SearchFiller_pojo_you_want_to_show_as_option_on_browser>" />
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="adults" cssClass="error" /></td>
       </tr>
```